# Can I combine direct descendant with first-child pseudo-selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a container div that could contain any number of children. I want to target all links that are direct descendants of the container div, and can do so with `.container > a`. But then, I want to give a different styling to the first link that is a direct descendent of the container. I assumed `.container > a:first-child` would perform this task, but it would seem not.

Note that using `.container a:first-child` would actually target the first two "incorrect" links, so I can't use that, I don't think.

Obviously I can rework the structure of the HTML, but I'd like to see if there's a CSS solution here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .container > a
            {
                background-color: plum;
            }

            .container > a:first-child
            {
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div><a href="#">Incorrect link</a></div>
            <div><div><a href="#">Incorrect link 2</a></div></div>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <a href="#">Category 1</a>
            <a href="#">Category 2</a>
            <a href="#">Category 3</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.container > a:first-of-type`

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cP7jZ/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Do you know why first-child doesn't work on the direct descendant?

Comment: first-child doesn't work to select the <a> because in your code, the first child of the "container" div is a <div>. the first-child selector will only select an element of the specified type if it is the very first child of the parent element. css-tricks.com has a good article on the difference between first-child and first-of-type: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Comment: Gotcha, had a bit of a brain fart, thinking it was picking the first child element that was an `<a>`. But like you said, it means in this "select the first child, only if it is an `<a>`".

Answer (score 0):

`.container > a:first-child` will work, as you can see from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/WcNZ6/)